# Why does my factorial end in zero in my while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, factorial

Here's my code:

```py
inputNum = eval(input("enter number to calculate factorial"))

total = inputNum

j = 1

while j < total and inputNum != 0 :
    j = j + 1
    print("j is", j)
    print("initial total is", total)
    inputNum = inputNum-1
    print("inputNum is", inputNum)
    total = total * inputNum
    print("total is", total)  
    #once you get to j==5, it is greater than inputNum == 3
    #I'm going to redefine while to be while j!=0
print("The factorial of", inputNum, "is", total)
```

Now, no matter what number I put in, the last four lines of output give me:

```
initial total is (inputNum!)
inputNum is 0
total is 0
The factorial of 0 is 0
```

I already said that `inputNum != 0`, so why won't stop once it gets to the correct answer?

Comment: You don't need both conditions.

Comment: Trace through the code line by line. See when `inputNum` takes on its different values. The loop doesn't exit *as soon as* you set it to zero, it exits at the end of the iteration when you do so. Also, `eval(input(...))` is a bad idea for so many reasons. Use `int(input(...))`

Comment: You initialize `total` to `inputNum` before entering the loop.  So when `inputNum` is `0`, you initialize `total` to `0`.  It never changes after that.  If you want to avoid that problem, initialize `total` to `1` before entering the loop, and then count up instead of down.  So for `3` factorial, rather than `3*2*1`, you would do `1*2*3.`  But for `0` you will end up with `1`.

Answer (score 0):

At the last iteration `inputNum` is `0`, and then you multiply `total` by `inputNum`.
For example, you can multiply `total` first, and then decrease `inputNum`

Here is the code:

```
inputNum = eval(input("enter number to calculate factorial "))

total = 1
while inputNum > 0:
    total = total * inputNum
    inputNum = inputNum - 1

print(total)
```

Result:

```
enter number to calculate factorial 5
120
```